# Array_splice acting as array_slice?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having issues understanding exactly what array_splice and array_slice do. From what I can tell array_splice should return an array AFTER taking out certain elements and array_slice should retrieve a slice of the array.

The following code from the [php.net/array_splice](http://php.net/array_splice) manual shows that this code should work.

```
$input = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");
var_dump(array_splice($input, 2));
// $input is now array("red", "green")

$input = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");
var_dump(array_slice($input, 2));
// $input is now array("red", "green")
```

However when I run this code on php 5.3.4 and 5.1.6 the results are

```
array
  0 => string 'blue' (length=4)
  1 => string 'yellow' (length=6)
array
  0 => string 'blue' (length=4)
  1 => string 'yellow' (length=6)
```

Am I misunderstanding the manual or is this a bug? It looks to me like array_splice is acting just like array_slice

Also it does not seem to do replacements

```
$input = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");
var_dump(array_splice($input, 2, 2, array('foo')));
```

outputs

```
array
  0 => string 'blue' (length=4)
  1 => string 'yellow' (length=6)
```

Can someone confirm this is a bug and if not explain how this SHOULD work?

EDIT:

Nvm I figured it out. Instead of using a var_dump on the array_splice I should be using $input as array_splice changes $input instead of returning the new values.

array_slice returns the values while array_splice sets the values to $input.

MODs please close or delete this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php):

> **Description**
>   array array_splice ( array &$input , int $offset [, int $length = 0 [, mixed $replacement ]] )
>
> Removes the elements designated by offset and length from the input array, and replaces them with the elements of the replacement array, if supplied.
>
> ...
>
> **Return Values**
>
> Returns the array consisting of the extracted elements.

You are just horribly, horribly confused.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out just after I hit post. Long morning without coffee yet. Since your post explains what I had come up with I will mark as the answer. You are right... we were very confused.

Answer (score 3):

splice removes a subset of array elements and inserts new elements in their location basically replacing them. slice just pulls a subset of array elements into a separate array.

Where you are misunderstanding is that the result of slice is returned from the function as a separate array, where splice actually manipulates the array that is passed in as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

In your first code example the comment state that what is left in the variable `$input` is `array("red", "green")` but makes no mention of the content returned by the `var_dump` which is what your tryouts returns